# Is there a way to create phantom tables in a postgres database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, sql-view

I have a table called `groups` in my postgres production server, they have a column called `manager_id`. What I'm trying to do is to create simulated look up tables base off the ids of the manager. For example, if I have the following rows for table `groups`:

```
|   id   |manager_id| ... |
|   1    |     1    | .
|   2    |     3    | .
|   4    |     1    |
|   5    |     2    |
|   7    |     2    |
```

I would like to access make believe tables like `group-1`

```
|   id   |manager_id| ... |
|   1    |     1    | .
|   4    |     1    | .
```

Or `group-2`

```
|   id   |manager_id| ... |
|   5    |     2    | .
|   7    |     2    | .
```

I am not sure if this is possible, and yes I'm aware I could query for it, but for the purpose of the question (and my very specific needs, which I am having trouble finding a workaround), can I do something like that? If yes, can I do it without duplicating data, just picking up references from the original one?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to do this. It would help to know how you plan to use this information once it is created? Temporary per session, persisted across sessions, as a sub select in another table, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Generally: just a use a `where` clause to filter on the manager you want the result from:

```
select *
from groups
where manager_id = 1
```

You could take one step forward and create views:

```
create view v_groups_1 as
select *
from groups
where manager_id = 1

create view v_groups_2 as
select *
from groups
where manager_id = 2
```

You can then run queries against the views just like you would do with a regular table.